# Pass values from a page to another

Tags: javascript, react-native

I have two arrays that contain data, I should pass these arrays to another page.

**First page**

```
stopConnection(array_acc_sx,array_acc_dx) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      console.log("Inizio stopConnection");
      Actions.registerattivita(this.state.array_acc_sx,this.state.array_acc_dx)
      // ....
    });
  }

  render() {
    return (
        // ......

        <View>
          <TouchableOpacity
            style={[style.button, style.buttonOK]}
            onPress={() =>
              this.stopConnection(
                this.state.array_acc_sx,
                this.state.array_acc_dx
              )
            }
          >
          // ....
```

and in the **RegisterAttivita.js**:

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      loading: true,
      array_acc_sx: [],
      array_acc_dx: [],
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.dataReceived(this.props.array_acc_sx,this.props.array_acc_dx)
  }

  dataReceived(array_acc_sx, array_acc_dx){
    console.log("data acc_sx: " + this.props.array_acc_sx)
    console.log("data acc_dx: " + this.props.array_acc_dx)
  }
```

So I should pass this.props.array_acc_sx and this.props.array_acc_dx to one page to another. At the moment I received that these two variables are [undefined].

How can I pass these two? 
Thank You

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First page

```
Actions.registerattivita({array_acc_sx:this.state.array_acc_sx,array_acc_dx:this.state.array_acc_dx});
```

2nd Page

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      loading: true,
      array_acc_sx: props.array_acc_sx,
      array_acc_dx: props.array_acc_dx
    };
  }
```

Comment: Ok I'm trying, and In the second page, if I should use these variables I use: this.props.array_acc_dx or this.props.array_acc_sx ?? :)

Comment: Yes use in that way (Y)